# spark dataframe to csv first column

Tags: csv, apache-spark, export-to-csv, apache-spark-sql

I am exporting a spark dataframe in java to a csv file. As I would like to sort the csv file later using unix sort tools I need to reorder the columns so that some column is first. Let's call is "sort_index" for now. How can I do this? Currently I am converting to csv using this code:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.parquetFile(somepath);
df.write()
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save(somepath);
```

The dataframe has some quoted fields so sorting using another column index always breaks. That's why I need some column to be first.

Comment: It is better to sort in Spark.

Comment: The problem is I have multiple parquet files and I am creating a big sorted csv file from them so sorting in spark is not an option for now as I would have to change the whole existing data pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double quotes use the following code:
    
     `df.write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("quoteMode,"NONE")
    .save(somepath);`